# why does iptables don't show rules?

Tags: iptables

A have a simple question about iptables. I have a centos machine with the following content in /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Dec 17 14:19:35 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2774:229756]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
```

but when I type iptables -L at the shell prompt, I see this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

why do I see a the chains without rules? what's the behavior of iptables in this case?
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think those rules are loaded by `iptables-restore`. Try to ping that computer (it should work), change `icmp` to `DROP`, restart the computer, and try to ping again. You shouldn't receive any response.

Comment: I have changed the icmp to DROP and the computer also responds. Maybe what the shell shows is what rules

Comment: Try first `iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables`, then `iptables -L`. The output should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your rules have been flushed a la:

```
iptables -F
```

Each change made by editing /etc/sysconfig/iptables will not be active until you restart the iptables service.

```
service iptables restart
```

If you wish to add rules "on-the-fly" you will need to use the iptables command to do it.

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "Logging"
```

now when you do:

```
iptables -L
```

you will see your new rule immmediately

Answer (score 0):

Do you have firewallD started? Seems in case I have installed firrewallD and it is not active and iptables yes,

```
iptables -L
```

Shows no rules.. 
After started firewalld all rules are then shown again.